# Как исправить баг с пропаданием части фона?

Tags: html, css, background

```css
section {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://svgshare.com/i/6RG.svg');
  height: 32px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пропадает часть фона, если изменить свойство `background-position`, то фон пропадает с другой стороны, если указать `background-size: 100% 100%`, фон просто растягивается на всю свою ширину, но не покрывает весь блок, как исправить?

Comment: там эта фигура на line сделана , нарисовать в polygon можете ? или вообще маской ещё проще будет

Answer (score 0):

У этого метода один минус - svg не тянется в след за `foreignObject`

```css
svg{
  display:block;
  width:80%;
  margin:1vh  auto;
}

.svg-item {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 80px;
}

.svg-item p {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.svg-item img {
  width: 90%;
  height: 290px;
  margin: 0 50px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 500">
      <text x="80" y="45" fill="blue" style="font-size:1.4em;font-variant:small-caps;">the girl of my life on the beach</text>
      <foreignObject  class="loaderForeighObject" width="900" height="300">
        <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="fbody">
          
          <div class="svg-item">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque necessitatibus incidunt nesciunt illo iure? Explicabo suscipit voluptatibus itaque, facere cupiditate odio officiis numquam fugiat illo sed nulla dolores debitis porro. </p>
            <img src="http://svoya.ucoz.ru/_ph/3/942254958.jpg" alt="">
          </div>      
        </body>
      </foreignObject>
  <polygon points="0,0 500,0 520,50 1000,50 1000,500 0,500" style="fill:transparent;stroke:#000; stroke-width:2px;"/>
</svg>
```